# Threads / Fibers - Clarification

Tags: multithreading, go, fibers

I'm a bit confused regarding the concept of "fibers" as to their relation to 1) threads and 2) what they're seen as by the Kernel.

To my understanding, a fiber is a thread that was created by a thread, and managed by its creating thread (i.e. perhaps a scheduler?). However, for all intensive purposes, I'd consider it as still being a "thread" and seen by the kernel as such.

The explanation I'm receiving from a colleague is that fibers are completely invisible to the kernel and run entirely in user space, and are in no way "threads", as per his email here:

> Threads are sometimes implemented in userspace libraries, thus called
>   user threads. The kernel is unaware of them, so they are managed and
>   scheduled in userspace. Some implementations base their user threads
>   on top of several kernel threads, to benefit from multi-processor
>   machines (M:N model). In this article the term "thread" (without
>   kernel or user qualifier) defaults to referring to kernel threads.
>   User threads as implemented by virtual machines are also called green
>   threads. User threads are generally fast to create and manage, but
>   cannot take advantage of multithreading or multiprocessing, and will
>   get blocked if all of their associated kernel threads get blocked even
>   if there are some user threads that are ready to run.
>
> Fibers are an even lighter unit of scheduling which are cooperatively
>   scheduled: a running fiber must explicitly "yield" to allow another
>   fiber to run, which makes their implementation much easier than kernel
>   or user threads. A fiber can be scheduled to run in any thread in the
>   same process. This permits applications to gain performance
>   improvements by managing scheduling themselves, instead of relying on
>   the kernel scheduler (which may not be tuned for the application).
>   Parallel programming environments such as OpenMP typically implement
>   their tasks through fibers. Closely related to fibers are coroutines,
>   with the distinction being that coroutines are a language-level
>   construct, while fibers are a system-level construct.

I'm hoping to get a little bit of a better explanation in terms of exactly what a fiber is (is it an actual thread as far as the os/kernel are concerned, and simply managed by its creating thread?).

I've researched it extensively via Google searches, but have only found one simple answer everywhere I've looked, including here: "A fiber is a thread that's created and managed by a thread."

If anyone has anything more informative they can share or point me to, it would be greatly appreciated. My colleagues argument is that Golang's Goroutines use "fibers" and those fibers are invisible to the OS - thus, a "correct" implementation of fibers. I, personally, feel that Goroutines are more closely related to coroutines, and do not implement a fiber/thread scenario at all...

Comment: Also, as an addition... A piece of code I wrote spawns off one thread per a core to wait for incoming socket connections. Upon receiving a connection request, a new thread is created by the thread that receives the request, and control of the fd is passed to that thread to handle the connection. At the same time, the worker threads are used to handle rw locks on a data structure in controls the job execution of the threads... Are the threads created by my schedulers worker threads considered "fibers," or "threads" ? To reiterate: is a fiber just a thread controlled in the manner I described?

Comment: I think the definition that fibers are system level just isn't factual... co-routines and fibers could be included or excluded from your system... or be the same thing, also go could implement them differently on a Mac, and a windows box or a BeOS, or on an embedded RTOS, I don't think it is a useful conversation as broad as your questions are... In a normal POSIX system there are Processes, and Threads, but fibers are user land scheduling implementations...

Comment: When you say "user land scheduling implementations," is that to say a fiber would not be a POSIX thread that's controlled by a user land scheduler? Or would a fiber actually be a POSIX thread that's simply controlled by a scheduler implemented in user land? 

The confusion comes in to play that my colleague insists a fiber would not in any way, shape or form be a POSIX thread that the underlying OS could even possibly see, and that it would be completely invisible to the OS/Kernel. My understanding is that it would, for instance, be a POSIX thread - but controlled by user land.

Comment: fibers could be scheduled to run on one worker thread, but technically a fiber could possibly start on one thread, and yield, then be rejoined on a different thread, (there aren't any C standard, or Posix library fibers so the semantics are loose)

Comment: Note that a POSIX thread (by its definition) can't be controlled from user land. If it is, it's not a POSIX thread. Userland threads are typically called 'green threads' (sometimes called 'fibers', as you're finding).

Comment: So, on that note, am I correct in saying something like a coroutine could be dubbed a "fiber" ?